# Express.js, Passport.js, cookie-session, logout doesn't delete cookies

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, cookie-session

I'm using `PassportJS` and this code for logout:

```
  .get("/logout", async (req, res) => {
    await req.logout();
    req.session = null;
    await res.clearCookie(process.env.PROJECT_TITLE.toLowerCase());
    await res.clearCookie(`${process.env.PROJECT_TITLE.toLowerCase()}.sig`);
    return res.redirect("/");
  });
```

It just changes the cookies but don't delete them. **Why?**

It does delete them if I use just this code:

```
  .get("/logout", async (req, res) => {
    await res.clearCookie(process.env.PROJECT_TITLE.toLowerCase());
    await res.clearCookie(`${process.env.PROJECT_TITLE.toLowerCase()}.sig`);
    return res.redirect("/");
  });
```

**Where am I wrong?**

Answer (score 3):

Put `req.session = null` in your logout route to clear the session cookie, as is done in [this tutorial](https://zeit.co/blog/serverless-express-js-lambdas-with-now-2). If that still doesn't work, try clearing your existing cookies for your project's URL in your browser and try again. I just had this issue and that's what fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still having problems with this, note that you should only put "req.session = null" and not req.logout() as it seems that this will lead to an incomplete http request. Obviously after thie, you can res.redirect('/some path')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to go against the docs: https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/logout/

Answer (score 0):

you need to destroy session, call `logout` from `req`, and clear cookie:

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next){
    req.session.destroy(function(e){
        req.logout();
        res.status(200).clearCookie('maemae', {
            path: '/'
        });
        return res.json({'ok': 1})
    });
});
```